# solution of $f'(x)+f(-x)=e^{-x^2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, error-function

let $f$ be a function such that $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$, I want to determine all functions of class $C^1$ such that $f'(x)+f(-x)=e^{-x^2}$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$, Now we have $f'(x)+f(-x)=e^{-x^2}$ this implies that $f'(x)=e^{-x^2}-f(-x)$, since $f'$ is of class $C^1$ this means that $f$ is of class $c^2$, That equation equivalent to :
$f''(x)=-2x e^{-x^2}-f'(-x)$ implies to $f''(x)-f(x)=-2x e^{-x^2}-e^{x^2}$ , if I take now $x\mapsto \lambda\cos(x)+\mu\sin(x),\lambda,\mu\in\mathbb R$ as a solution without second term in order to get particular solution it would be complicated and given by error function which forbide me to get a general solution, I ask now if there is any simple way to solve that functional ?

Comment: You have a sneaky error in your calculations: when you differentiate $f'(x)=e^{-x^2}-f(-x)$ to get the formula for $f''(x)$, you need to remember that $\frac{d}{dx}f(-x)\neq f'(-x)$...

Comment: Also, your particular solution of the differential equation seems like the wrong form to me; that form _should_ be good for the homogeneous version, but your 'base' particular solution shouldn't look like that.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki, I think yes and this is exactly my problem I think that particular solution works only for e^(x) in RHS

Comment: See also the similar questions https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2360494/how-to-find-solutions-to-equation-fxfx-kf-x-0,  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3410487/how-to-solve-fx-f-x

Comment: Following your idea, we are actually led to solve $$y(x)-y''(x)=(1-2x)e^{-x^2}.$$ Then by plugging the general solution to the original one, *Mathematica* finds that $$y(x)=C(\cos x-\sin x)+\frac{e^{-x^2}}{\sqrt{2}}\left[i^{1/2}D\left(\frac{1}{2}-ix\right)+i^{-1/2}D\left(\frac{1}{2}+ix\right)\right],$$ where $D(x)=e^{-x^2}\int_{0}^{x}e^{t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t$ is the [Dawson function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dawson_function) and $C$ is an arbitrary constant.

Comment: I got $y''(x)+y(x)=(1-2x)e^{-x^2}.$

Comment: Your equation is correct, I made a typo in my previous comment. The solution thereof is indeed correct, and as a sanity check, note that the general-solution part $\cos x-\sin x$ solves the homogeneous equation $y''+y=0$.

Comment: ok @SangchulLee I suppose your comment is for me.